# How change first value in SSRS chart

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2012

I have a report which shows the number of files. There is a pie chart with #Index link to the legend. The first value started at 0. But it may confuse users. Is it possible to change the first number of #Index alias to number 1? I mean change only information that printing in the report for users without skipping 0 values. I tried to convert to string and int functions on #Index, and it didn't work.
[An example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ed4ie.png)

Comment: What's wrong with `[value] + 1`?

Comment: @Larnu I tried =CInt([#INDEX])+1 and it throw an exception. If I input [#INDEX]+1, in the report it shows as text.

Comment: is `#Index` *not* an integer? If not, then fix what ever is defining it as a `varchar` first.

Comment: @Larnu #Index is something from this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/formatting-data-points-on-a-chart-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15 . That's why I don't know how to modify it.